# How to close input when click on document in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created an input with a button that when I click on button, input show and remove. But I also want to remove input when I click on DOM, and I know I should set `addEventListeners` to DOM. But I don't know what function I should use.

[image]

[image]

```
//Html
<div class="search">
  <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Search . . ." />
  <button class="btn">
    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
  </button>
</div>

//Js
const searchSection = document.querySelector(".search");
const input = document.querySelector(".input");
const searchBtn = document.querySelector(".btn");

searchBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
 searchSection.classList.toggle("active");
 input.focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vanilla JS way to listen for click events is listen for all clicks on the document, and then check if the clicked element has the selector you care about.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    // If the clicked element doesn't have the right selector, bail
    if (!event.target.matches('.click-me')) return;

    // Don't follow the link
    event.preventDefault();

    // Log the clicked element in the console
    console.log(event.target);

}, false);
```

This approach is called event delegation, and it works by taking advantage of something called event bubbling.

You can read more on [Listening for click events with vanilla JavaScript](https://gomakethings.com/listening-for-click-events-with-vanilla-javascript/)